# I wrote a shell script to remove old files inside /shell

Tags: development, localhost, mage-shell, simplexml

I would like to move all files that are older than 24 hours. Currently I'm just deleting them. When I'm in the shell folder and I try to run the script in terminal: `php clean_fc_export.php` i get the error:

```
require_once 'abstract.php';

class Clean_Fullcircle_Old_Export_Files extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{
    public function fclean()
    {
        /** define the directory **/
        $dir = "var/report/";

        /** cycle through all files in the directory */
        foreach (glob($dir."*") as $file) {
            /** if file is 24 hours (86400 seconds) old then delete it */
            if (filemtime($file) < time() - 86400) {
                unlink($file);
            }
        }
    }

    // Shell script point of entry
    public function run()
    {
    }

    // Usage instructions
    public function usageHelp()
    {
        return <<<USAGE
Usage:  php -f scriptname.php -- [options]
  --argname <argvalue>       Argument description
  help                   This help
USAGE;
    }

    // Instantiate
    $shell = new Clean_Fullcircle_Old_Export_Files();

    // Initiate script
    $shell->run();
}
```

---

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function simplexml_load_string() in /var/www/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php:510
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php(498): Varien_Simplexml_Config->loadString('<?xml version="...', 'Mage_Core_Model...')
#1 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(274): Varien_Simplexml_Config->loadFile('/var/www/app/et...')
#2 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(391): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadBase()
#3 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(275): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initBaseConfig()
#4 /var/www/app/Mage.php(616): Mage_Core_Model_App->init('admin', 'store', Array)
#5 /var/www/shell/abstract.php(86): Mage::app('admin', 'store')
#6 /var/www/shell/clean_fc_export.php(44): Mage_Shell_Abstract->__construct()
#7 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
```

I looked inside my phpinfo() file and it shows that i have Simplexml loaded and active.

[image: phpinfo]

I'm running vagrant and VM with a lamp stack.
I made sure that `extension=php_xmlrpc.dll` was un-commented out in both `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini` and `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.dll` libraries is for the windows, you should use `simplexml.so` on Linux. If you run the script from the CLI you can use next command to check is there extension installed or not:

```
php -i
```

you should see many configurations, and can found something like this:

> SimpleXML
>
> Simplexml support => enabled
>
> Revision => $Id: b8b5c37931a53e50a937c0aef2a26d351e173215 $
>
> Schema support => enabled

or just type:

```
php -i | grep "Simplexml"
```

return should look like this:

> Simplexml support => enabled